# UWP - Refresh VideoEncodingProperties after edition

Tags: c#, uwp, video-editing

I made a crop in my video width and I need to get the new Width, but I can't refresh the VideoEncodingProperties (MediaClip) in order to use the new properties after the edition.
How can I generate the new Properties?

Comment: Could you please provide more information to help us further check the problem for you? It would be better if you can tell us how you clip the video and where you want to refresh and get this Properties.